# Finding the 'earliest' composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider these data:

```
ID       Year     Code1    Code2
-------- -------- -------- --------
ABC123   99/00    10010    A1121
ABC123   00/01    10010    A1131
ABC123   01/02    10010    A1141
XYZ567   06/07    12501    B2213
XYZ567   07/08    12501    B2223
```

These four fields make up the primary key and I need to find the earliest occurrence of each instance of `ID`, with the three other keys. So, in this case, I would want:

```
ID       Year     Code1    Code2
-------- -------- -------- --------
ABC123   99/00    10010    A1121
XYZ567   06/07    12501    B2213
```

In Oracle, my current solution is to aggregate over the fourth character of `Code2`, which is the year index, and return the minimum then recompose the key (i.e., the varying `Year` part); however, this is obviously ambiguous and *may* not map one-to-one. (Also, this method is slow!) An ordering won't work either because, in general, there will be multiple values under `ID` and `Year` doesn't include the century.

I was thinking that maybe I could do a subquery for each `ID` and then do an ordering and pick the first item (i.e. `ROWNUM=1`). However, this requires at least two levels of subquery and, thus, is both awkward and slow... So, any better ideas?! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [analytic functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions004.htm#i81407) were invented for!  You want something like:

```
select id, year, code1, code2 from
( select id, year, code1, code2,
         row_number() over (partition by id order by ???) as rn
  from mytable
)
where rn = 1
```

I left the `order by` as ??? because I don't fully understand what you want here.  It could be:

```
order by year, code1, code2
```

or

```
order by substr(code2,4,1), year
```

or whatever.

Comment: ...`FIRST_VALUE` also does something similar