# Finding most recent record in MySQL temporal DB with composite primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that is very similar to:
[Finding the 'earliest' composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993633/finding-the-earliest-composite-primary-key)

However, I'm using MySQL 5.0.77 and need to get only the most recent record.  My table, TABLE_1, looks like this:

```
OID     PROP_TYPE     EFFECTIVE_DATE        PROP_VALUE
-----   ----------    -------------------   ----------
00123   NA010         2003-05-30 15:52:15   JAMES
00123   NA010         2004-02-30 10:12:18   FRED
00123   NA011         2003-05-30 08:25:41   WILLIAMS
00123   NA011         2006-01-15 22:12:38   DANIELS
00123   NA012         2003-05-30 08:25:41   (704) 242-2124
```

There is a composite key of OID, PROP_TYPE and EFFECTIVE_DATE, so I'm looking for a select statement that retrieves the following:

```
OID       PROP_TYPE    EFFECTIVE_DATE       PROP_VALUE
-----     ---------    -------------------   -------
00123     NA010        2004-02-30 10:12:18   FRED
00123     NA011        2006-01-15 22:12:38   DANIELS
00123     NA012        2003-05-30 08:25:41   (704) 242-2124
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    TABLE_1 AS t
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
            t2.PROP_TYPE,
            t2.OID
        FROM
            TABLE_1 AS t2
        GROUP BY
            t2.PROP_TYPE,
            t2.OID
    ) AS MaxDate
    ON t.EFFECTIVE_DATE=MaxDate.EFFECTIVE_DATE
    AND t.PROP_TYPE=MaxDate.PROP_TYPE
    AND t.OID=MaxDate.OID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select OID, PROP_TYPE, EFFECTIVE_DATE, PROP_VALUE
  from TABLE_1
 where OID, PROP_TYPE, EFFECTIVE_DATE in
  (select OID, PROP_TYPE, MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) from TABLE_1 group by OID, PROP_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM 
        TABLE_1 AS t
    JOIN
        ( SELECT oid, prop_type, MAX(effective_date) AS effective_date
          FROM TABLE_1 
          GROUP BY oid, prop_type
        ) AS g
      ON  (g.oid, g.prop_type, g.effective_date)
        = (t.oid, t.prop_type, t.effective_date)
```

An index on `(oid, prop_type, effective_date, prop_value)` would probably help for performance.